# Does the law of excluded middle imply the axiom of choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I know that [the Axiom of Choice implies Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaconescu%27s_theorem), but I haven't been able to find any discussion of the other direction.

Does the law of excluded middle imply the axiom of choice?

Here's a stab at a proof, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

AC says that there is always a function f that can take a set $X$ with $\geq 1$ elements and chooses for each $x \in X$ whether $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ (exclusive).

For any $x \in X$, let P be the proposition that $x \in A \land \neg (x \in B)$ and let Q be the proposition that $x \in B \land \neg (x \in A)$.

By LEM, $P \vee \neg P$ and $Q \vee \neg Q$. So there are the following cases:

1. $P \land Q$ . Therefore $x \in A \land \neg (x \in A)$. Contradiction.
2. $P \land \neg Q$. Therefore $f(x) \in A \land \neg (f(x) \in B)$.
3. $\neg P \land Q$. Thefore $f(x) \in B \land \neg (f(x) \in A)$.
4. $\neg P \land \neg Q$. Therefore $x \in B \land \neg (x \in B)$. Contradiction.

Comment: That is not what AC says!

Comment: Counterexample: $\mathsf{ZF\neg C}$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if one was able to arrive at the Axiom Of Choice by any deductive process, it would no longer be an axiom, right?

Comment: No, you would have proven that AC is weaker than whatever hypotheses you've been using. It's now a theorem, but only in the specific system you chose. It is itself proven that AC is independent of ZF, so neither will imply the other.

Comment: In standard logic, EM is true, no need to use AC to prove it.  That link shows that in so-called "constructive set theory", where EM may fail, we can prove EM from AC (where AC is stated in the appropriate way).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The axiom of choice states that given a family of non-empty sets, there is a function mapping each of those sets to an element of the set. The idea is to be able to move from $\forall a\in A\exists x(x\in a)$ to $\exists f\forall a\in A(f(a)\in a)$.

What you're talking about is existential instantiation, i.e. if $X$ is not empty, then we can "name" an element of it. There is also no $A$ and $B$ involved (and in your statement there is no information about them either). People sometimes mistake EI to be an instance of $\sf AC$, but that is not the case.

And of course, we know that LEM does not imply $\sf AC$, since we know that $\sf ZF$ is consistent with $\lnot\sf AC$ while LEM holds.

Comment: I see that I misunderstood AC. But I'm still a little fuzzy on it. I think the key part I'm missing is what a [choice function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function) is (Wikipedia definition: "A choice function (selector, selection) is a mathematical function f that is defined on some collection X of nonempty sets and assigns to each set S in that collection some element f(S) of S".  How does this differs from the "naming" you describe?To take the example where X is a collection (not sure what this means) of A and B, then wouldn't a choice function choose A or B for each x in X?

Comment: Have you read about [existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation) as well?

Comment: Yep, how is it related? Should I be looking at the $\exists$ on the RHS or the LHS of AC?

Comment: Also, I see now that the "proof" is silly–the conclusion is not anything like even AC as I misdefined it.

Answer (score 2):

Your meaning of "AC" is clearly wrong.

Of course, we usually accept LEM as a postulate, but it is known that AC is independent of ZF. So, the answer is "no".